# How best to share a QooXDoo using Git?

Tags: javascript, git, qooxdoo

I'm developing a little project with [QooXDoo](http://qooxdoo.org/) and want to share the source with some friends. Should I just check in the whole project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `build` and `cache` directories to the relevant `.gitignore` files (these directories they are the equivalent of 'object' files, so they should not be stored in version control unless you have a very good reason).

As for Qooxdoo itself, I usually place it next to the project so it's easy to duplicate the setup. I end up with something like this

```
/
    tmp
        qooxdoo-sdk-xxx
        my-app-directory
```

HTH

Comment: Both nice answers, but i think this one is a little bit more what i wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best approach would be to just check in your application and a little instruction file how to setup a qooxdoo SDK.

This way the developers can work with your application locally and using a qooxdoo SDK to work against.

As long as you do not need to work against the current trunk it's better to work with the latest SDK.
See the [download](http://qooxdoo.org/download) page at qooxdoo.org

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at [remOcular](https://github.com/oetiker/remOcular) a qooxdoo frontend with perl backend, complete with autoconf setup.